# Is it possible to do cloud based backup of a Xamarin Realm DB file per user to something like AWS S3?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, xamarin, cloud, realm

I am creating an offline application and trying to use Realm for Xamarin.

In the future, I may need to do cloud based backups of the user data.

I was thinking that I could just upload their Realm DB file to some cloud storage, and have some sort of way of matching a user account to their DB file?

Maybe a combination of AWS S3 and Cognito?

It doesn't necessarily need to be AWS. It could be Azure, Google, etc.

Am I going about this the right way, or is there a better way?

Basically, instead of backing up a user's data to their Dropbox or iCloud, have it centrally backed up to a cloud server.

**UPDATE**

I don't think the Xamarin Realm API allows writing the DB to a file yet, so I may have to use SQLite.

Would I be able to use store the SQLite DB as an AWS S3 Bucket, connected to the user's AWS Cognito credentials?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/s3-integration-lowlevelapi.html

Comment: Why is this needed? matching a user account to their DB file.

Comment: So each user can have a backup of their data

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's a bit of an unusual approach. How frequent do you expect these backups to be made? And would you want them to be incremental? Realm database files are binary, so you would probably end up sending large amounts of data from this approach.

Comment: It is mostly just a backup that they can restore from if they lost their phone data or changed devices, those sort of use cases. Maybe a backup once a day. I know there is a big thread on Realm syncing in discussion. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913. Are there any best practices for doing this sort of user app data backup? With SQLite perhaps?